# (Cognitive Linguistics) Is Morse Code an example of a sign, a symbol or an index?

Tags: linguistics

Would Morse Code be an example of a symbol or an icon (or an index)?

We had a lesson on it last week, and it made more sense as an icon to me (auditory input -> image representation; dots are shorter sounds, lines are longer sounds), but my friends tell me it's either a symbol or an index. I'm extremely confused and I can't find anything online.

Comment: Are you using the words "icon", "sign", "index" and "symbol" to refer to specific terminology in Cognitive Linguistics? If so, can you provide the definitions you have in mind.

If you are using the words in a general sense, Morse code does not define specific signs or symbols, only an encoding of short and long signals (which can be sound, light, symbols). You could then argue the mapping of letters to these signals defines an index.

Comment: This belongs on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Linguistics or even philosophy SE. Both seem to have "semiotics" tags. Or ask your tutor/teacher/lecturer.

Comment: This belongs on Linguistics SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would Morse Code be an example of a symbol or an icon (or an index)?

There is a clue in the name: it is a **code**.

OED:

> 2c.   **Morse code**  n. a code devised by Morse for use with the electric telegraph, in which the letters are represented by combinations of long and short electrical signals represented audibly or visually, or by long and short flashes of light or (in writing) dashes and dots.

And **Code:**

> II. A system of signs or symbols.
>
> 4.a. ... In later use: any system by which information or instructions are conveyed concisely according to a set of previously agreed correspondences between words, symbols, sequences of numbers, or actions and the words or meaning to be understood, sometimes with the aim that this should be intelligible only to the intended recipient; esp. (now chiefly historical) such a system used for economy or secrecy in the transmission of telegraphic messages.
> The use of printed lists of words taken from dictionaries or of artificial groups of letters or numbers, alongside the corresponding words, phrases, or sentences, was introduced for semaphore telegraphy in the late 18th cent., and adopted for electric telegraphy in the mid 19th cent.

This runs in to

> b. A method of communication in which each letter (or group of letters) in a written message is systematically substituted by another, or by a symbol, to enable transmission (e.g. in a semaphore alphabet or by electrical telegraphy).

From this, it can be seen that, whether semaphore or Morse, the code refers to the symbols (i.e the shapes and angles in semaphore). The fact that you can hear one and not the other is irrelevant.

As a further point, Morse code had first to be written before it could be transmitted as sounds. Thus the original was certainly a code made from symbols.

Comment: "Morse code had first to be written before it could be transmitted as sounds." Is this true? Why would it need a written form prior to transmission?

Comment: @dubious If Morse had not written it, how would the first person to receive it have known what it meant? If he did not know what it meant - what use would it have been? Are you suggesting that Morse hummed it to that person until he understood?

Comment: Ah, the penny drops. It sounded like you were saying that every time someone sent Morse, they had to compose the msg on paper first.